# Непонятная ошибка при работе с массивами

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы

В коде ниже выдается непонятная ошибка.

Как сделать правильно?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int zapmass(int* Z, int a,int  b)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            Z[i][j] = rand() % 11;
        }
    }
    return (*Z);
}

void vuvid(int& Z, int  a, int  b)
{
    cout << "Matrutsa:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        cout << "| ";
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            cout << Z[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int const a = 4, b = 5, c = 8;
    int* A[a][b];
    int* B[b][c];
    zapmass(A[a][b], a, b);
    zapmass(B[b][c], b, c);
    vuvid(*A[a][b], a, b);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: и не будет работать, ибо нет выделения памяти для динамических массивов. Подробно утром.

Comment: А какую конкретно ошибку выводит?

Comment: `int* A[a][b]` — здесь вы выделяете двумерную таблицу неинициализированных указателей типа `int*`, указывающих невесть куда. Аналогично и в строке ниже.

Comment: гляньте https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-array-tutorial-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

и в качестве дополнения, позвольте добавить, есть еще арифметика указателей. Любой массив N-размерности можно привести к одномерному и с ним поработать. Что-то вроде этого:

PS:

1. убрал SRAND - без него хоть результаты не такие одинаковые в каждыйый
       момент времени, да и можно и без него )) и избавились попутно от
       #include time.h
2. % 10; - вместо 11... так "Matrutsa:" красивее

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void zapmass( int &Z, int m, int n)

{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
             (&Z+i*n)[j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void vuvid( int &Z, int  m, int  n)
{
    cout << "Matrutsa:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "| ";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << (&Z+i*n)[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int const a = 4, b = 5, c = 8;

    int A[a][b];
    int B[b][c];

    zapmass(**A, a, b);
    zapmass(**B, b, c);
    vuvid(**A, a, b);
    vuvid(**B, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Пример:[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/CoAnAV)

Answer (score 5):

Начнём по порядку.

Судя по коду, Вы недавно писали программы вида:

```cpp
int main()
{
  const int l = 4;
  const int m = 5;
  const int n = 8;
  int A[l][m];
  int B[m][n];

  for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        /*...*/ A[i][j] /*...*/;
        /*...*/ B[j][k] /*...*/;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Это всё прекрасно работало, в рамках одной функции.
Но здесь есть один подлый нюанс.
Типы переменных `A` и `B` достаточно сложные.

- у переменной `A` - это `int [4][5]`, т.е. массив фиксированной длинны 4 массивов фиксированной длины 5;
- у переменной `B` - это `int [5][8]`, т.е. массив фиксированной длинны 5 массивов фиксированной длины 8;

Это **разные типы!!!** И мы не можем написать одну функцию для их обработки. Нам нужны разные функции для обработки разных типов данных. Что можно сделать используя шаблоны, но это не ваш случай.

Именно из-за выведения этих типов компилятором, нельзя убрать слово `const` в определении `l`, `m`, `n`.

Компилятор может привести:

- тип переменной `A` к `int (*)[5]`, т.е. массив произвольной длинны массивов фиксированной длины 5;
- тип переменной `B` к `int (*)[8]`, т.е. массив произвольной длинны массивов фиксированной длины 8;

Но мы опять получаем разные типы. Эти типы ты как раз и мог увидеть в сообщениях об ошибках.

Нам нужен один тип данных для всех матриц. Озвучим его: "массив произвольной длины массивов произвольной длины". Это `int **`.

Тогда объявление матриц будет таким:

```cpp
const int l = 4;
const int m = 5;
const int n = 8;
int **A;
int **B;
```

мы также можем передавать их в общую функцию:

```cpp
void myfun(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
  /* ... */
}

int main() {
  /* ... */
  myfun(A, l, m);
  myfun(B, m, n);
}
```

Но остаётся вопрос инициализации переменных `A` и `B`. И тут вам должны были показать следующий код:

```cpp
int **matrix = new int *[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  matrix[i] = new int[cols];
}
```

Т.к. в определении матриц мы не можем указать конкретные размеры, то они будут определятся при динамическом выделении памяти.

Теперь можем всё объединить в одну программу:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int **matrix_new(int rows, int cols)
{
  int **matrix = new int *[rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = new int[cols];
  }
  return matrix;
}

void matrix_delete(int **matrix, int rows)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    delete[] matrix[i];
  }
  delete matrix;
}

void matrix_random_fill(int **matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 11;
    }
  }
}

void matrix_print(int **matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
      cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int l = 4;
  const int m = 5;
  const int n = 8;
  int **A = matrix_new(l, m);
  int **B = matrix_new(m, n);

  srand(time(0));
  matrix_random_fill(A, l, m);
  matrix_random_fill(B, m, n);

  std::cout << "Matrix A:\n";
  matrix_print(A, l, m);

  std::cout << "Matrix B:\n";
  matrix_print(B, m, n);

  matrix_delete(A, l);
  matrix_delete(B, m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

да здесь ошибка за ошибкой (((

```
int zapmass(int* Z, int a,int  b)
{
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
   Z[i] = new int[b];
}

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
        Z[i][j] = rand() % 11;
    }
}

return Z;
}


main(){
int const a = 4, b = 5, c = 8;
int* A = new int*[a]
int* B = new int*[b]
zapmass(&A, a, b);
zapmass(&B, b, c);
vuvid(A, a, b);

system("pause")
return 0;
}
```

Пробуй запускать, я на машине не пробовал, должно работать. Функция vuvid() вроде без ошибок.
Почитай в интернете больше информации об указателях...

Comment: Ответ, конечно не доработан, поэтому Вам накидали минусов, однако я  добавлю Вам плюс в "карму", чтобы у Вас не пропало желание помогать людям. "...Почитай в интернете больше информации об указателях..." - ИМХО, такой совет без ссылки имеет нулевую ценность.