# Как передать в функцию двухмерный массив с неизвестными параметрами

Tags: c++, графы

```
int kol_graph(int n, int a[][]) {
   int cur = 0;
    vector <int> was(n, -1);
    queue <int> q;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (was[i] != -1)
           continue;
        q.push(i);
        while (!q.empty())
        {
              int v = q.front();
              q.pop();
              if (was[v] != -1)
                 continue;
              was[v] = cur;
              for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  if (a[i][j] != 0 && was[j] == -1)
                     q.push(j);
        }
        return cur++;
    }   
}
```

Вот функция, но в случае с двухмерным массивом его не получается объявить вначале. Как быть? Мне нужна именно функция.

Comment: `int kol_graph(int n, int **a) ` размерность массива надо будет передавать отдельными аргументами, либо `int a[][]` замени на 'const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& a`

Comment: @ffk если 1 способом как передать размерность

Comment: `int kol_graph(int n, int **a, int sizex, int sizey)`

Comment: @ffk выдаёт такую ошибку невозможно преобразовать ‘Тип int [][]’ в ‘int**’ для параметра ‘1’ в ‘int kol_graph(Тип int**, int, int)’

Comment: @keks, объявление вида `int [m][n]` обозначает массив просто элементов размером `m * n * sizeof(int)` байт. То есть этот непрерывный кусок памяти не имеет отношения к массивам указателей, о которых шла речь выше.

Comment: @keks, из недавних тем [Непонятная ошибка при работе с массивами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737572/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: @keks Запостил ответ с разными вариантами как можно передать двумерный массив. Второй вариант на мой взгляд самый лучший и универсальный.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8767166/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы передать двумерный массив нужно обязательно передавать его размерности, либо используя в аргументах `int (&a)[15][10]` где 15 и 10 должны быть ровно те константы которые были при объявлении массива откуда он передался, либо нужно выводить эти размеры через шаблонные параметры если они заранее не известны, либо нужно передать массив как `int * a` плюс отдельно его размеры, но в последнем случае индексировать массив нужно будет по формуле через умножение и сложение. Ещё есть 4-й вариант, когда можно передавать как `int a[][10]` он похож на первый вариант за тем исключением что в 4м варианте массив деградируется до указателя, т.е. не сохраняется исходный тип массива, потому sizeof в четвёртом варианте вернёт размер указателя (4 или 8) а в первом варианте вернёт 600 (4 * 15 * 10), в этом смысле 1й вариант лучше 4-го т.к. он сохраняет полный исходный тип, также в 4-м варианте можно опустить первую размерность т.к. для вычисления индекса используются все кроме первой размерности. Самый лучший вариант по моему мнению это 2-й т.к. в нём не нужно знать заранее размерности, шаблон автоматом выводит размерности, также полностью сохраняется исходный тип, не деградируется до указателя.

Вот все 4 варианта, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/N4lG/1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void var1(int (&m)[15][10]) {
    cout << sizeof(m) << endl;
    cout << m[8][7] << endl;
}

template <int Size1, int Size2>
void var2(int (&m)[Size1][Size2]) {
    cout << sizeof(m) << endl;
    cout << m[8][7] << endl;
}

void var3(int * m, int s1, int s2) {
    cout << sizeof(m) << endl;
    cout << m[s2 * 8 + 7] << endl;
}

void var4(int m[][10]) {
    cout << sizeof(m) << endl;
    cout << m[8][7] << endl;
}

int main() {
    int m[15][10];
    m[8][7] = 123;
    var1(m);
    var2(m);
    var3((int*)m, 15, 10);
    var4(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: как по мне, то есть вариант получше - делаем класс/структуру, полями которого будут сам массив, его размерности. И в результате проблема передачи решается сама собой

Comment: @KoVadim По-моему шаблонный вариант 2-й вполне достаточный, ему не нужно указывать никаких размерностей, он сам их выводит, при этом не теряет типа массива вообще, не деградирует его до указателя.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы передать двухмерный массив в функцию, не задумываясь о его конкретной реализации, можно его передать по ссылке на тип, заданный в шаблоне:

```
template <typename C>
void f(const C& a)
{
  for (auto&& row : a) {
    for (auto && item: row)
      std::cout << item << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Это работает как для встроенного массива, так и для динамических структур таких как `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

```
int main()
{
  int a[][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} };
  f(a);
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} };
  f(v);
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/YCfjVA):

```
$  c++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
0 1 
2 3 
4 5 
0 1 
2 3 
4 5
```